# Emberjs Page slide effects on change route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, css-transitions

I checked the outlook.com email look, and was trying to add some transition effects to my app, so I found this pluging http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/, is not really what I want, but is there an easy way to add transition effects to ember ?

Comment: Try http://www.the.gs/fresh/curtain/example/#section-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember Animated Outlet is an easy way to add animated transitions between routes.  https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet